# How to apply a catalog price rule in category and display name of catalog price rule in product view page in magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to implement this task I don't know .Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have capture video.
http://youtu.be/HYyQGmeFfek?hd=1

Can you please comment why you need to display created promo on product detail page?  generally, the promo code will send to the customer via mail.

Comment: Hi@Pratik Kamani, Thanks your response to my question immediately.My aim is catalog price rule name displayed applied categories only in product view page .Can you please help me?

Comment: @DileepKumar I think Are you talking about "Shopping Cart Price Rules".
you can generate coupon with catalog price rules.
 you can apply for promotion on catalog or product or  various payment condition.

Comment: No, I talking about catalog price rules displayed applied categories only in product view page

Comment: @DileepKumar
I am not clear about your requirement. I think now are you able to create promo codes for this video.
 Please elaborate your second issue with a live example or screenshot.

Comment: my requirement is display name of catalog price rule  in product view page

Comment: VIVO
$100.00  $90.00 here not display name of catalog price rule
add to cart button above?Can you please help me?

Comment: I think this does not default Magento functionality.
 we need to create extension about this, this is customer requirement, we need to work on this and it takes some time. Send screenshot on pilukamani@gmail.com

Comment: How to create the extension ? Can you please help me?